# ENS registry wrong ens name

Tags: ens

I tried to bit on an ens registry with the following command:

```
var bid = ethRegistrar.shaBid(web3.sha3('mydomain.eth'), eth.accounts[0], web3.toWei(1, 'ether'), web3.sha3('secret'));
```

after I placed the bid I realized that the name should be 'mydomain' and not 'mydomain.eth'

Is there any chance to reclaim my ETH and bid again with the correct name?

Answer (score 3):

During the 48 hour reveal period, make sure to [reveal bid](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html#revealing-your-bid) using the same arguments (like web3.sha3('mydomain.eth')).

You should be the sole winner and will be charged the minimum price of 0.01 ETH but get the rest back when you finalize the auction.

You can run all the [commands](https://docs.ens.domains/en/latest/userguide.html) again this time with the correct name.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean during the reveal period of the correct ('mydomain' and not 'mydomain.eth')?

Comment: You have to reveal bid using the same arguments: if you used 'mydomain.eth' then you have to use that.  Next time, when you bid on 'mydomain' you have to reveal using 'mydomain'.  ('mydomain' is actually no longer available to be bid on.)

Comment: I actually wanted to bid on 'ethchain' but I placed the bit on 'ethchain.eth' instead. ('mydomain' was just a synonym). What do I have to do now? Is there still some hope?

Comment: During the 48 hour reveal period, do a reveal on ethchain.eth and finalize auction. Then submit a bid on ethchain: there's only around 11 hours left to bid on ethchain.  Once bid on ethchain, during the 48 hour reveal period make sure to reveal bid.

Comment: How can I find out when the reveal period of ethchain.eth starts? Is there place where I can find all running auctions?

Comment: https://etherscan.io/enslookup can help but it won't show all running auctions.  Since names are hashed, you can't find out if a name is being auctioned, unless the name is popular.